# Problems with simple C bootstrap/kernel

Tags: c, x86, kernel, nasm, osdev

Recently I've become interested in writing my own really really basic OS.
I wrote (well, copied) some basic Assembly that establishes a stack and does some basic things and this seemed to work fine, however attempting to introduce C into the mix has screwed everything up.

I have two main project files: loader.s which is some NASM that creates the stack and calls my C function, and kernel.c which contains the basic C function.

My issue at the moment is essentially that QEMU freezes up when I run my kernel.bin file. I'm guessing there are any number of things wrong with my code -- perhaps this question isn't really appropriate for a StackOverflow format due to its extreme specificity. My project files are as follows:

**loader.s:**

```
BITS 16                         ; 16 Bits

extern kmain                    ; Our 'proper' kernel function in C

loader:
    mov ax, 07C0h           ; Move the starting address [7C00h] into 'ax'
    add ax, 32              ; Leave 32 16 byte blocks [200h] for the 512 code segment
    mov ss, ax              ; Set 'stack segment' to the start of our stack
    mov sp, 4096            ; Set the stack pointer to the end of our stack [4096 bytes in size]

    mov ax, 07C0h           ; Use 'ax' to set 'ds'
    mov ds, ax              ; Set data segment to where we're loaded
    mov es, ax              ; Set our extra segment

    call kmain              ; Call the kernel proper

    cli                     ; Clear ints

    jmp $                   ; Hang


; Since putting these in and booting the image without '-kernel' can't find
; a bootable device, we'll comment these out for now and run the ROM with
; the '-kernel' flag in QEMU
        ;times 510-($-$$) db 0          ; Pad remained of our boot sector with 0s
        ;dw 0xAA55                      ; The standard 'magic word' boot sig
```

**kernel.c:**

```
#include <stdint.h>

void kmain(void)
{
        unsigned char *vidmem = (char*)0xB8000; //Video memory address
        vidmem[0] = 65; //The character 'A'
        vidmem[1] = 0x07; //Light grey (7) on black (0)
}
```

I compile everything like so:

> nasm -f elf -o loader.o loader.s
>
> i386-elf-gcc -I/usr/include -o kernel.o -c kernel.c -Wall -nostdlib -fno-builtin -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs
>
> i386-elf-ld -T linker.ld -o kernel.bin loader.o kernel.o

And then test like so:

> qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel kernel.bin

Hopefully someone can have a look over this for me -- the code snippets aren't massively long.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be flat binary? What parses/loads you ELF file?

Comment: BIN is a flat binary format, so I guess it is? I don't know. I just lob my BIN straight to QEMU, tell it that it's a kernel using '-kernel' (because treating it like a full kernel and bootloader without using '-kernel' and using the magic boot sig to a 512 byte segment wasn't working out for some reason, even though in my eyes it should), and hope for the best (which apparently isn't working out for me).

Comment: This code looks familiar, any chance it is part of http://wiki.osdev.org Barebones tutorial ?

Comment: Part of it was based off that code, yes. [As a sidenote: If I remember correctly, using the exact code from there actually created the same or a similar problem as I'm experiencing with this code -- but I doubt this is an environment problem as that may suggest, I've tried the BIN fine (and the IMG in the case of the code from that tutorial) on other machines and it has the same problems]

Comment: @joesavage: The OSDev Bare Bones tutorial is based on the assumption that you are using the GRUB bootloader for first and second stage (as is detailed in the tutorial itself). As such, there is no 16-bit code involved there, and the linker script is aiming at generating an ELF file - i.e., that tutorial aims at a *completely* different environment as your "first stage" approach.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Gosh, where to begin? (rhughes, is that you?)

The code from `loader.s` goes into the Master Boot Record (MBR). The MBR, however, also holds the partition table of the hard drive. So, once you *assembled* the `loader.s`, you have to *merge* it with the MBR: The code from `loader.s`, the partition table from the MBR. If you just copy the `loader.s` code into the MBR, you killed your hard drive's partitioning. To properly do the merge, you have to know where exactly the partition table is located in the MBR...

The output from `loader.s`, which goes into the MBR, is called a "first stage bootloader". Due to the things described above, you only have 436 bytes in that first stage. One thing you *cannot* do at this point is slapping some C compiler output on top of that (i.e. making your binary larger than one sector, the MBR) and copying that to the hard drive. While it *might* work temporarily on an old hard drive, modern ones carry yet more partitioning information in sector 1 onward, which would be destroyed by your copying.

The idea is that you compile `kernel.c` into a *separate* binary, the "second stage". The *first* stage, in the 436 bytes available, then uses the BIOS (or EFI) to *load* the second stage from a specific point on the hard drive (because you won't be able to add partition table and file system parsing to the first stage), then *jump* to that just-loaded code. Since the second stage isn't under the same kind of size limitation, it can then go ahead to do the *proper* thing, i.e. parse the partitioning information, find the "home" partition, parse its file system, then load and parse the *actual* kernel binary.

I hope you are aware that I am looking at all this from low-earth orbit. Bootloading is one heck of an involved process, and no-one can hope to detail it in one SO posting. Hence, there are websites dedicated to these subjects, like [OSDev](http://osdev.org). But be warned: This kind of development takes *experienced* programmers, people capable of doing professional-grade research, asking questions the smart way, and carrying their own weight. Since these skills are on a general decline these days, OS development websites have a tendency for grumpy reactions if you approach it wrongly.(*)

(*): Or they toss uncommented source at you, like dwalter did just as I finished this post. ;-)

**Edit:** Of course, none of this is the actual reason why the emulator freezes. i386-elf-gcc is a compiler generating code for 32-bit protected mode, assuming a "flat" memory model, i.e. code / data segments beginning at zero. Your `loader.s` is 16-bit real mode code (as stated by the `BITS 16` part), which *does not* activate protected mode, and *does not* initialize the segment registers to the values expected by GCC, and then proceeds to jump to the code generated by GCC under false assumptions... BAM.

Comment: @DevSolar: you're right, undocumented code from my side wasn't that helpful. I'll remove it and maybe repost it with documentation. Or OP should have a look at http://wiki.osdev.org.

Comment: @Joesavage1: The resource recommendation is in my post, hyperlinked for your convenience.

Comment: @joesavage A bootloader starts in 16-bit real mode then later switches to the 32-bit protected mode. But by passing qemu the -kernel flag you are using qemu's built-in bootloader. Therefore, your loader.s is not the actual bootloader but the glue between the bootloader and the kernel. As DevSolar says, the emulator freezes because loader.s is in 16-bit (real mode) code and kernel.c is in 32-bit mode.

Comment: A bootloader is limited to 512 bytes and will typically load the kernel into memory and do some things which require real mode to be accomplished. Some multi-stage bootloaders (GRUB) will load the second-stage, which will then switch it to protected mode and load the kernel. But by passing qemu the -kernel flag, it does all this for you. So your code should all be formatted for protected mode.

Comment: The `times` and `dw 0xAA55` would be used for an actual bootloader. But since I assume you want loader.s to be the glue between the bootloader and the kernel, you wouldn't use that.